# Unable to rerender the WMS vector layer using react + openlayers after updating the CQL parameters

Tags: reactjs, openlayers, geoserver, wms

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Map from "ol/Map";
import { OSM } from "ol/source";
import View from "ol/View";
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/Tile";
import TileWMS from "ol/source/TileWMS";
import { fromLonLat } from "ol/proj";


function MapComponent(props) {
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
  const geoserver_base_url = '......'

  const mapRef = useRef()
  mapRef.current = map
  const [selectionState, setSelectionState] = useState(true);

  const handleFilterChange = () => {
    setSelectionState(!selectionState);
    console.log(selectionState)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const initialMap = new Map({
      target: "map",
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM(),
        }),
        new TileLayer({
          source: new TileWMS({
            url: geoserver_base_url + "/geoserver/sr_vectors_lg_ws/wms",
            params: {
              layers: "sr_vectors_lg_ws:sr_vectors_p1_0",
              format: "image/png",
              transparent: true,
              // cql_filter: selectionState ? 'confidence=90' : 'confidence=30'
            },
          }),
        }),
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: fromLonLat([-10897871, 3524431]),
        projection: "EPSG:3857",
        zoom: 5,
      }),
    });
    setMap(initialMap);
  }, [selectionState]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (map) {
      const tileLayer = map.getLayers().getArray()[1];
      const source = tileLayer.getSource();
      const newParams = {
        ...source.getParams(),
        cql_filter: selectionState ? 'confidence=70' : 'confidence=90'
      };
      const newSource = new TileWMS({
        url: geoserver_base_url + "/geoserver/sr_vectors_lg_ws/wms",
        params: newParams
      });
      tileLayer.setSource(newSource);
    }
  }, [selectionState]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleFilterChange} id ="button"> Filter Selection</button>
      <div id="map" style={{ marginTop:"30px",width: "100%", height: "100vh" }}></div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MapComponent;
```

Expectation: When i click on the Filter Selection button, the CQL filter needs be applied to the vector layer and toggle its value between 70 and 90 while properly updating it on the map.

Actual: The CQL filter value updates and the WMS call is made with the updated cql_filter. However, the layer doesn't rerender and it remains the same.

Comment: you could try layer.getSource()?.changed()

Comment: Does the URL return an image with the cql filter?